# Rename NServiceBus.Host.exe

Tags: nservicebus

This may very well be a silly question, but I cannot find any documentation on this or where anyone has really asked this question except here [NServiceBus Yahoo Groups](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/16218). I want to rename my NServiceBus.Host.exe, even though they have different names in the services group when I install the service, in task management all the services are NServiceBus.Host.exe. I have tried renaming the exe, but of course this has issues with deployment, and it simply will not run as per the url I had posted, encountering an endpoint config error.

I've looked through the configuration options and I do not see anything that looks as such an option, if anyone knows a good way to do this, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like not a very good idea. That road is bound to be riddled with potholes.

In order to tell the processes apart in Task Manager, there's a pretty simple solution.

Go to View -> Select Columns, and add "Command Line" which is just a few up from the bottom.

This will show you the full path to the specific NServiceBus.Host.exe instance, along with the command line arguments, which can give you valuable information like the [Profiles](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles) that were used.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be riddled with potholes? Allowing you to simply rename the service shouldn't be problematic, even though I do not see anything that allows such a thing to happen. I understand there are ways to find out by digging a little further in the information, I was able to compare them by process IDs.

Comment: The name of an assembly (and an exe is just another assembly) is that assembly's identity, and NServiceBus employs assembly scanning and dynamic loading to do its business. Although I can't speak to specific examples, I find it extremely likely that some portions of the NServiceBus code make the assumption that the host process will be named "NServiceBus.Host.exe".